# Issues with Django REST JWT tokens not refreshing?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I've been implementing JWT tokens with my django REST app and I got it mostly working with the help of simple-jwt found [here](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I can sign in and obtain my refresh and access tokens but I noticed that if I attempt to refresh my token via `jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view()` I receive an error that reads:

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized

{
    "detail": "Token is invalid or expired",
    "code": "token_not_valid"
}
```

I've been trying to find a solution across reddit and stackoverflow but to no avail. Why isn't my token refreshing? Here's the relevant parts of my code:

### Relevant Code

`settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer', 'Token'),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
}
```

`models.py`

```
#custom user profile model
class User(AbstractUser):
    link1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    link2 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    link3 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    link4 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    about_me = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

`urls.py`

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views

urlpatterns += [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/token/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

### Expected vs actual output

Expected to refresh token using `api/token/refresh/` after receiving it via `api/token/`, but was met with an error saying it was invalid/expired.

### What I've tried

Honestly I mostly tried just refreshing the page and redoing the same steps over and over hoping something would finally change cause I really don't have a clue how this is happening, considering I followed the 3 simple steps from the docs and somehow failed that.

### Edit

I noticed that when I decode my refresh token on JWT.io, that the payload is unrecognizable. What's going on?

Comment: Did it get solved ? I am facing the same issue now

Comment: will you please check my question I think I am having the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73460841/refresh-token-becomming-invalid-suddenly-even-when-it-has-not-expired-django-r